# Display issue when hovering over any of the tags in the "Responses" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, responses

There is a display issue when hovering over any of the tags in the "Responses" tab. The popover on the bottom is overlapped with the below revision's tag and icons. But the popover on top doesn't have any display issue.

**Screenshot for reference**

[image: Tag overlap issue - image]

**GIF for reference:**

[image: Tag overlap issue - GIF]

Comment: Likely related to this issue (and/or fix): [When viewing a question's edit history that includes tag edits, the opacity is broken when hovering over a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419802/15497888)

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've addressed this issue now. We had the same issue on [another page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419802/1458738) so copy pasting my response from there:

> This issue occurred while I was adding keyboard navigation support to
> our tag popovers as part of our [accessibility initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419586/announcing-design-accessibility-updates-on-so). It turns out
> we're using clip-path to animate the collapsible component here which
> creates a new css stacking context. Thus causing the painting order
> problem (different stacking contexts don't share the same z-index
> context).
>
> I had to disable the collapse/expand animation for now to get rid of
> the issue. We will look into alternative animation strategies for a
> long term fix but this change should address the immediate issue.